# How to listen to an incoming sms using NativeScript?

Tags: android, angular, android-intent, nativescript

I want to listen to the RECEIVE_SMS intent to read a One Time Password delivered via a text message, in Nativescript(using Angular2). I am following the steps outlined in http://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/application. However, when i run the code i get the following error:

```
app/app.component.ts(12,6): error TS1005: ';' expected.
app/app.component.ts(12,14): error TS1005: ';' expected.
app/app.component.ts(12,48): error TS1005: ',' expected.
app/app.component.ts(12,57): error TS1005: ',' expected.
app/app.component.ts(12,67): error TS1005: ',' expected.
app/app.component.ts(12,82): error TS1138: Parameter declaration expected.
app/app.component.ts(12,118): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'android'.
app/app.component.ts(12,151): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'android'.
app/app.component.ts(13,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'android'.
app/app.component.ts(14,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'android'.
app/app.component.ts(17,4): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
app/app.component.ts(18,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

Here's my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <ActionBar title="My App"></ActionBar>
    <!-- Your UI components go here -->
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  // Your TypeScript logic goes here
  app.android.registerBroadcastReceiver(android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED, function onReceiveCallback(context: android.content.Context, intent: android.content.Intent) {
    console.log('rcvd');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you did not import the required modules

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";
import * as platform from "tns-core-modules/platform";

//declare this to use android variable
declare var android:any;

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <ActionBar title="My App"></ActionBar>
    <!-- Your UI components go here -->
   `
 })
export class AppComponent{

 ngOnInit(){
app.android.registerBroadcastReceiver(android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED, function onReceiveCallback(context: android.content.Context, intent: android.content.Intent) {
console.log('rcvd');
 });}
}
```

Comment: The typescript compiler also requires the `tns-platform-declarations` folder in node_modules with the android types

Comment: Can you please suggest step by step process to add SMS receiver in angular as I have added 'tns-core-modules' and 'tns-platform-declarations' but still it's giving me Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/application'

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct. You should put your listening function inside the `ngOnInit` hook:

```
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core'

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {

    // your code here
    }
}
```